# Generating Dynamic Linq For Jquery DataTables

Tags: c#, jquery, linq

I'm attempting to build an adapter to make using [JQuery Datables](https://datatables.net/) with Entity Framework considerably simpler. The adapter is very similar to the one built by Telerik in their [Kendo UI Extensions](https://github.com/kendo-labs/dlinq-helpers). I've managed to get most of the logic working, but the final piece that's giving me some trouble is getting the dynamically generated Linq to work.

I've looked into both [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) and [Dynamic Expressions](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic/wiki/Dynamic-Expressions), and I'm a bit torn on how to approach this. I'm currently using the Dynamic Linq extension with limited success. It appears to work fine with Varchar and Int fields, but it stumbles with dates.

I'm using it like so:

```
public class Search
{
    [DataMember(Name = "value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "regex")]
    public string Regex { get; set; }

    public string ToExpression(IList<Column> columns)
    {
        var list = columns.Select(column => $"{column.Data}.Contains.(@{columns.IndexOf(column)})").ToList();

        return string.Join("or", list);
    }
}

public class FilterExpression
{
    public string Filter { get; }
    public IEnumerable<object> Values { get; }

    public FilterExpression(IEnumerable<Column> columns, Search search)
    {
        if (search.Value == null) return;
        var list = columns.Where(n => n.Searchable).ToList();

        Filter = ToExpression(list);
        Values = list.Select(n => search.Value);
    }

    private static string ToExpression(IEnumerable<Column> columns)
    {
        var colList = columns.Where(n => n.Searchable).ToList();
        var list = colList.Select(column => $"{column.Data}.ToString().Contains(@{colList.IndexOf(column)})").ToList();

        return string.Join(" or ", list);
    }
}

public static IQueryable Where(this IQueryable source, FilterExpression filterExpression)
{
    return filterExpression?.Values == null ? source : source.Where(filterExpression.Filter, filterExpression.Values.ToArray());
}
```

The above works for most cases, but again Dates are a bit of a problem. The goal is to prevent developers from having to manually write their Linq `Where` statements and instead allow the adapter to simply generate it.

Again, the above works for both INT fields and VARCHAR, but if I include a DATE field in the model, the error I get is: `System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/exception-linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-tostring
```

Check this one out.
Bascially when you work with linq to entites, it creats a query which is fired on sql server. ToString() works with in memory objects. 
If the object was in memory ,it would have worked just fine. Please go through the link.